# What version of Dokka goes with what version of Kotlin?

Tags: maven, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-dokka

Whenever the Kotlin and Dokka versions are not compatible, things might break oddly in Gradle and Maven builds.  I cannot find anywhere a list of the compatible versions between the two.  What is the version compatibility?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Kotlin topics are present in SO.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the matching compatible versions:

```
Kotlin Version    Dokka Version
----------------|-----------------
1.0.0             0.9.7
1.0.1             0.9.7
all               0.9.8 or later
```

Since `0.9.8` Dokka no longer can conflict with the compiler classes since it embeds a shaded version of the compiler.

See current versions on [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.dokka/dokka-maven-plugin)

Comment: AFAIK, since 0.9.8 dokka shades compiler classes so it's no longer needed to have corresponding versions of dokka and kotlin complier. @yole could correct me if I'm wrong.